# How to print a NSString using AirPrint?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, printing, nsstring, airprint

Im having real trouble with this one. I dont know what is wrong, but it spits this out:

ERROR: attempting to display print options with no printing   source(item/items/formatter/renderer) set

The code works if i set it to print a png image, but not the contents of a NSString.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)pushPrint:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YY     HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString* currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [dateFormatter release]; 

    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:t[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Results Printout\n"
                                                              "\n"
                                                              "%@\n"
                                                              "\n"
                                                              "\n"
                                                              "%@", currentTime, pasteboard.string] ofType:nil];

    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    UIPrintInteractionController *print = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

    print.delegate = self;
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = [path lastPathComponent];
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    print.printInfo = printInfo;
    print.showsPageRange = YES;
    print.printingItem = myData;

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *,BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *print,BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) {
            NSLog(@"houston we have a problem");
        }
    };
    [print presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be wanting to print a plain `NSString`, yet you are trying to load a file with a file path that cannot be valid. Thus, `myData` is very likely `nil` (please confirm with the debugger) and thus the error message is correct (`print.printingItem` must not be `nil`).

To print a simple text, create an instance of `UISimpleTextPrintFormatter` (with `initWithText:`) and assign that instance to `print.printFormatter`.

Comment: I'm trying to print the content of a uitextview, but the printer simulator prints it all in one line. If I replace "\n" with "\n\n", the result isn't always the same on the printer simulator. I use a UISimpleTextPrintFormatter and initWithText. Did you have similar problems?

Comment: @Ole Begemann Thanks Man! You have helped me many times! :-)
I want to know how can I come to know that something is missing in my code.